# losetup does not decrypt device in Ubuntu 11.4 as before

Tags: disk-encryption, ubuntu-11.04

I had an external volume mounted using `losetup` for about two years.
It was created using Ubuntu 9.4 and I used the same Ubuntu installation throughout all dist upgrades.
Now as I bought a new laptop I set up a fresh Ubuntu 11.4 installation on it.

Problem is: `losetup -e twofish /dev/loop0 /dev/sdb2` does not decrypt the volume anymore. The data in `/dev/loop0` contains apparently random data. I am sure I entered the correct password.

I modprobe'd cryptoloop and twofish.

My question is: Has Canonical done some obscure changes to losetup like adding a salt? Does losetup depend on configuration files I did not know about? How can I decrypt the volume on my now laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I forgot to install `loop-aes-utils`.